# Looking for a PDF Library like PDFBox for PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Is there any PDF library like [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) available for PHP?

Comment: Maybe you could take some time to *describe* what you want, instead of making people do *extra* work before being able to help you for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/).

It is a PDF library for PHP which sounds like it ought to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I recently wrote this https://github.com/imalhasaranga/PDFBox and it can do basic pdf to image and image to pdf conversion but indeed if you are looking for full functionality you can go for TCPDF

Answer (score 1):

[fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) is great for creating PDF documents, I have used it many times. It cannot parse PDF docs though, if thats what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

- [MPDF](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php)
- [DomPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

Prefer MPDF myself. Found DomPDF to be quite flaky in the past, whereas MPDF although heavy was more robust.